# How to shrink VirtualBox vdi for HFS+ guest OS

Tags: virtualbox, hfs+

I have a VirtualBox guest OS drive formatted as HFS+ which is 20GB. I resized it's hard disk virtual media vdi file to 40GB and now want to reduce it to 32GB.

The extra 20GB I added to the vdi with the Virtual Media Manager has never been used by the guest OS and is not visible to it.

I've tried using:

`VBoxManage modifymedium  disk myhd.vdi --compact`

...which completes successfully but does not shrink the vdi and...

`VBoxManage modifyhd myhd.vdi --resize 32768`

which produces the error...

```
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to resize medium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Shrinking is not yet supported for medium 'C:\Users\me\VirtualBox VMs\Snow Leopard\Snow Leopard.vdi'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED (0x80bb0009), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleModifyMedium(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 768 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

Is there any way to shrink a VirtualBox vdi with a (OSX) HFS+ guest or migrate the guest hard disk to a new 20GB or 32GB vdi?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because the *Format variant* of the image is *fixed default*. But you can only resize *dynamic default*.

Issue following command to check your VM's format variant:

```
VBoxManage showhdinfo "c:\Dev\VMs\ubuntu18.04\18.04_ubuntu.vdi"
```

You get following output (yours would have different values):

```
UUID:           57ce025b-f7e6-3435-8417-3453634535
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       c:\Dev\VMs\ubuntu18.04\18.04_ubuntu.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Format variant: fixed default
Capacity:       10240 MBytes
Size on disk:   9617 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
```

If you see *fixed default* you must first clone the image with following command:

```
VBoxManage clonehd c:\Dev\VMs\ubuntu18.04\18.04_ubuntu.vdi "new-image-name".vdi
```

This creates a new image file "new-image-name".vdi which has dynamic default as Format variant. That one can then be resized.

Comment: Thanks, when I examine the virtual media file in VirtualBox's Virtual Media Manager it is listed as `Storage Details: Dynamically allocated storage` confirming it is already a dynamic disk. It's a while ago now but if I remember correctly I found dynamic disks can not be shrunk when the contained hard drive is formatted as HFS+.